# How if I insert multiple empty space or ' ' will be replace with NULL in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use 'insert' function but with empty space or ' ', but i dont know how to make it? And how if i want to make multiple empty space and will be automatically replace by NULL? 
For Example

```
INSERT INTO databaseName (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) 
       VALUES ('Name', '','','Date')
```

Comment: ' ' will not be considered as null. It will simply be considered as a blank string.

Comment: 1. You insert into TABLENAME not DATABASENAME.  2.what is your expected outcome? what would we see if we were to select that inserted row?

Comment: @ Aditya Can we make a procedure or function to replace that as NULL?

Comment: @G B Sory i mean tableName. I want if i insert '' in the column, so will be replace by NULL in the table column

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but I think I understand what you're asking.

Normally I'd just use the NULL keyword:

```
INSERT INTO databaseName (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) 
   VALUES ('Name', NULL, NULL,'Date')
```

But I get the sense that the values for these strings are built in code, and you don't know up front when they'll be empty and when they won't. If they are empty you'd prefer NULLs in the database. In that case, Sql Server includes the [`NULLIF()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) function:

```
INSERT INTO databaseName (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) 
   VALUES ('Name', NULLIF('',''), NULLIF('',''),'Date')
```

I'm concerned, though, that this means you're building this code in a way that will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Make sure you're not using string concatenation to put values into your queries. If you do, you'll find that your app's database **will** be hacked. Hopefully, you're using query parameters, which avoid the sql injection attack. If you do, your sql code will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO databaseName (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4) 
   VALUES ('Name', NULLIF(@Column2Parameter,''), NULLIF(@Column3Parameter,''),'Date')
```

You could also handle this with a trigger, but I don't like to rely on trigger unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: can we make one funtion to replace empty space automatically in  every columns ?